# which event calling in the previous activity when the onbackpressed is called in the current activity?

Tags: android, events, back

when I click the button to close the application it back to a previous screen that the activity is still open, I need to close it. so I want to handle the event return to onbackpressed

Comment: how do you doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

When you will start a new `Activity` start like this:

```
// Launch Dashboard Screen
Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DashboardActivity.class);
// Close all views before launching Dashboard
dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(dashboard);
// Close Login Screen
finish();
```

Comment: what happens now.
There are 5 activities.
loginActivity,
MenuActivity,
OccurrencesListActivity,
OccurrencesEditActivity,
CorrectionsEditActivity.

Navigation happens like this:

loginActivity --> MenuActivity (onfinish) --> OccurrencesListActivity (onFinish) -->  OccurrencesEditActivity (onFinish) --> CorrectionsEditActivity. 
open menu options --> click button close app. (finish()) --> re-open loginActivity --> button closed --> OccurrencesListActivity is opening. =/

Comment: whenever you will open a new actvity from a old activity you have to place this code. In every 5 activity.

Comment: in all the activities I treat through onbackpress BaseActivity event of a class that is inherited by all others. I call her and finish the event.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBackPressed` method and close both your `Activity`